# Edit Form displaying the same id from the first row in the Gallery

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

[image]

I am trying to pre-populate my EditForm1 by passing on my > button via OnSelect: Set(varSelectedRecord, ThisItem);Navigate(Screen2) that sits within the Gallery1

The EditForm1 has Item: varSelectedRecord

The result is the following. As you can see, its populating the PanelClass, Year, Month and Budget cards correctly. However, for some reason it still shows the Budget_ID as 1.

[image]

Respectively, this record should have/show a Budget_ID of 8 in this case.

Comment: Budget_ID shows as `1` not `8` in your example of `varSelectedRecord`.

Answer (score 1):

**Its either:**

1. The `Default` property of the Budget_ID column (should be set to `Parent.Default`) OR
2. You need to add `ResetForm(FormName); EditForm(FormName)` to the `OnSelect` of the ">" in your gallery.

Report back here and let us know what you find.